# How to loop(for) through data with conditions in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

Example data:

```
[
    {
        "field_name": "mobile",
        "field_value": "917845546369",
        "type": "primary"
    },
    {
        "field_name": "email",
        "field_value": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "type": "primary"
    },
    {
        "field_name": "name",
        "field_value": "XYZ",
        "type": "primary"
    }
]
```

I need to loop through it and get the `field_value` field. The challenge is I need to get it based on `field_name`.

Expected result is get field_value

```
ex: if field_name=mobile
    mobile=field_value

mobile = 917845546369
email = xyz@gmail.com
name = XYZ
```

Comment: What is the condition here? you say "based on `field_name`". Based on what? Can you add a desired output of this example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like:

```
data = [
    {
        "field_name": "mobile",
        "field_value": "917845546369",
        "type": "primary"
    },
    {
        "field_name": "email",
        "field_value": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "type": "primary"
    },
    {
        "field_name": "name",
        "field_value": "XYZ",
        "type": "primary"
    }
]

result = []
for k, i in enumerate(data):
    if some_condition(i):
       # This will include only the needed elements,
       # or you can "Nullify" any data[k]["field"] here instead
       result.append(i)

# or simply...

result = [i["field_name"] for i in data if some_condition(i)]
```

When `some_condition(i)` can be anything like `i["field_value"] == 22` or `foo(i)` where foo returns a boolean.

Comment: It sounds like he wants field_value depending on field_name. So probably: result = [i["field_value"] for i in data if some_condition(i["field_name"])]

Comment: yes exactly as required and it worked. Thank you.